# search for the values from the tree and return node value

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the value of node from the tree. tree class so far has only find which returns address of the node, but how should I get the value of the node. And I am not allowed to edit by class file.

```
const dataType* find(const dataType &Data) const 
{
   if (rootNode == NULL)
     return NULL;
   else 
     return rootNode->find(Data);
}
```

they is no search function and I am not allow to edit either so how could I get value from the tree node. I have seen the other example of searching but how can I do in cpp file

Comment: It looks like that function `find` returns a pointer to the `Data` object you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but simply dereferncing the pointer will give you the value:

```
const dataType* dtrPtr = find(someData);
if ( dtrPtr != NULL)
{
    const dataType& foundDtr = *dtrPtr;
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply helped me a lot. Finally working. I forget to dereference the that was a issues.